# I can't undersatand the following example of deadlock

Tags: deadlock

Consider the following algorithm for copying a file:
1 Open the source file for exclusive access. (Assume that this blocks until
no other process has the file open. Once this call returns, other processes
that attempt to open the file block until the file has been closed again by
the current process.)
2 Open the destination file for exclusive access.
3 Copy data from source to destination.
4 Close the destination file.
5 Close the source file.
What can possibly go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A competing thread or process could be using a different algorithm, and open the destination file first, then sit there waiting for the source file to become available.... Both processes would be waiting for each other.